# Unity 5.2 default 3rd person controller makes character fly upwards when moving forward

Tags: unity, movement, character, third-person-view

I'm new to Unity, and already dealing with a problem using the default third person controller script. I am trying to move and animate the player, but I have a problem, as when I try to move the character it moves beautifully but not only vertically and horizontally - it also moves up on the y axis! It just keeps going higher and higher, and though it's quite funny, it really messes the gameplay.

Here are screenshots of what happens, and yes, I do have gravity turned on:
[image: Screenshot of character on the ground, then in the air after pressing forward]

Comment: Welcome to the Community! Can you please add some details in your question. Like your code snippet, screenshots etc?

Comment: Thanks :) I added the link to code it's a standard Unity script so I don't know why it wouldn't work.. I'll screenshot what happens to the character as well..

Comment: I think you mean the Y axis.  X and Z are horizontal ("ground").  Interesting problem, though.

Comment: Please add the code *snippet* not a link to the file. And only the interesting part :)

Comment: I am not sure what part could be responsible for this problem so I added whole code and part of it wasn't recgonised so it wasn't really useful that's why I added the link :) and yeah I meant Y but don't have good typing skills apparently..

Comment: Even if the code was actually *available* through the link, I feel that this is an example of "debugging question without minimal code to replicate the problem".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since they original code is not posted on this site, I am not going to click on the link. Instead, I will give you a very simple 3rd person controller script that illustrates how movement can be handled on a basic level. And to be honest, animations are much better handled using the Animation Controller Component. It uses a state machine to control the animations and you can add int parameters. In addition to the simple movement in 3rd person view, I will also comment on how you could take advantage of the Animation Controller in scripting.

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class ThirdPersonCamera : MonoBehaviour
{
    public Camera cam;
    public GameObject character;
    public Animator anim; // Gets the Animator component and
    // is better used when it is attached to the character

    void followCharacter()
    {
        if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.LeftArrow))
        {
            cam.transform.position -= new Vector3(1, 0, 0);
            //anim.SetInt(1); if the parameter is an integer
            // it will move to that specific animation
        }

        else if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.RightArrow))
        {
            cam.transform.position += new Vector3(1, 0, 0);
        }

        else if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.UpArrow))
        {
            cam.transform.position += new Vector3(0, 0, 1);
        }

        else if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.DownArrow))
        {
            cam.transform.position -= new Vector3(0, 0, 1);
        }
    }

    void Update()
    {
        followCharacter();
    }
}
```

Comment: Nice it is much appreciated! :) I'll do my best to implement this so I guess wish me luck and thanks a lot :)

Comment: Note that while the original default controller uses `rigidbody` to move with physics, this is a more direct approach, that will not incorporate physics as such. You would also want to *at least* multiply the movement by `Time.deltaTime` (eg. `new Vector3(0, 0, (1*Time.deltaTime))`), as without it, movement may be jittery, and be (frame dependant?). That is, users with more processing power will have the `Update()` function run more frequently than other users, and in turn will move faster.